# What is the type of a returned element of an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I was wondering what is the return type when trying to access an element of an array in swift, is it an optional? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the array elements should be of the type defined by the array. (If it's an array `[String]` then each element will be a string.

I guess you COULD make an array of optionals in swift if you wanted to (`[String?]`) since optionals are not nil, they are an object with no contents. In that case each element in the array would be an optional.